# Button show different height between 2 android os

Tags: android, android-xml

I create an app that support android 2.3 to the latest android os. But I have a problem with my layout. Here is my xml code http://pastebin.com/JLHnADNu and this is the button shows on android 4 [image]

but this button will look different on android 2.3 here is the screen shot [image]

my question is how do I achieve the same result on both OS. Thank you.

Comment: you have to create layout acoording to dp like hdpi -mdpi-xhdpi

Comment: have you applied height wrap_content for Button?

Comment: @PG_Android yes I did, but it didn't change the height.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto Give it to fix height or apply weight for button.

Comment: try to apply `android:minHeight = "48dp"` to your button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TableLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:background="#428bca"
   android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow>
        <Button
           android:id="@+id/simpan_situs"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:layout_height="50dp" //or whatever the height you want
           android:text="@string/simpan"/>
        <Button
           android:id="@+id/gambar_situs"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:layout_height="50dp" //or whatever the height you want
           android:text="@string/gambar"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Also read **[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)**

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, I just add the same height for the button `android:layout_height="50dp"`. Thank you.

Comment: try to add android:textSize="30dp" to the buttons, as I did in my edited answer

Answer (score -1):

Button height and width depend on the screen size like if its mdpi, hdpi, xdpi or xxdpi

Comment: is it your answer ? or comment